# How can I check if client terminated the gRPC connection?

Tags: node.js, tcp, nestjs, grpc, http2

In Nestjs, I am creating a gRPC bidirectional stream connection between the server and client.

Here is what I understand. A gRPC stream is using HTTP/2, which will start a single TCP connection and multiplex multiple streams over it. When the stream is closed, the TCP connection is still open and can be reused for future requests.

Based on the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc#call-stream-handler), My gRPC server will be implemented like this:

```
@GrpcStreamCall('StreamService', 'openStream')
async openStream(requestStream: ServerDuplexStream<Message, Message>) {
        requestStream.on('close', async () => {
            // This event is emitted when the stream is closed. Not when the TCP connection is closed.
        });
}
```

Since the `close` event is emitted when the stream is closed. Not when the TCP connection is closed/terminated. I want a way to detect/handle if the client terminated the TCP connection from the server-side How?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. gRPC does not expose connection information to the server application.